# Pushing new element in array overwriting previous element

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a few cards and on click, I am calling a function in which I have an empty array and I want to push the clicked element to the array. However, the problem is that it is overwriting the previously clicked element.  I went through each and every stack overflow post regarding this but I couldn't find the solution to my issue. Your help would mean a lot to me.

```
const Shop = () => {
const [cartItems,setCartItems] = useState(0);

function handleCart(e){
    setCartItems(cartItems+1);
    const clickedItem = e.target.parentElement;
    const itemsArr = [];
    itemsArr.push(clickedItem);
    console.log(itemsArr);

}
```

Comment: SHow me from where you are calling this function

Comment: Perhaps you want to define `const itemsArr = []` **outside** of the `handleCart` function?

Comment: It doesn't solve the issue. I tried that.

Comment: @sojin                                                                                                                          
            <button className="addCart"onClick={handleCart}>Add to cart</button>

Answer (score -1):

you need to define itemsArr outside of the component, so that it doesn't get re-defined each time the button is clicked (or the component rerender). Or, better, you can use a state variable for it:

```
const Shop = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  function handleCart(e){
    setCartItems(cartItems+1);
    const clickedItem = e.target.parentElement;
    setItems(items => item.concat([clickedItem]));
  }

  console.log(items);
  ...
};
```

Comment: thanks! I applied your approach and it worked. Though it is not the exact answer of this question but in this case, it's more than enough to move ahead. Thanks for the help!